# Quartz CRON trigger not fired when expected

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have a simple quartz trigger running in Spring 2.5.6-SEC01.

Trigger definition looks like this:

```
<bean id="AdvicesCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="AdvicesQuartzJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 20/15 * * * ?"/>
</bean>
```

This is my scheduler factory:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="AdvicesCronTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I've read [this documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html) about firing CRON triggers from Quartz. This is an excerpt:

> CronTrigger Example 1 - an expression
> to create a trigger that simply fires
> every 5 minutes
>
> "0 0/5 * * * ?"

Today I fired my program at 9:40. This is my execution output:

**Edit:** Bobby is right in his appreciation. I've updatted my execution log:

> 2010-02-11 09:50:00,000 INFO  - START
>
> 2010-02-11 10:20:00,000 INFO  - START
>
> 2010-02-11 10:35:00,000 INFO  - START
>
> 2010-02-11 10:50:00,000 INFO  - START
>
> 2010-02-11 11:20:00,000 INFO  - START
>
> 2010-02-11 11:35:00,000 INFO  - START

I expected that this trigger will be fired at

> 9:50
>
> 10:05
>
> 10:20
>
> 10:35
>
> ...

How to accomplish this? Which CRON expression use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `20/15` part of the cron expression means every 15 minutes after the 20'th minute of the hour. This means that it will always start at the 20'th minute.

I have never tested it but maybe an expression like this one would be what you are searching for :
    `0 */15 * * * ?`

Comment: Why then Quartz fires my trigger at 9:50 after executen the app at 9:40?

Comment: Because I think it translates the 20/15 expression in a 20,35,50 expression.

Comment: Problem is, I have some (2 for now) quartz triggers and I don't want this to be triggered at same time that other triggers but I want same periodicity for all. I wrote 10/15 on first, 20/15 on second trigger.

Comment: Then would it be that bad to just write the exact minutes you want them to be triggered? Also you could control this by setting one at second 0 and the other one at second 30.

Answer (score 1):

Not to give you a non-related answer, but sometimes it makes sense to use some services instead of trying to do it yourself :) Take a look at http://www.cronservice.co.uk/new/, http://scheduler.codeeffects.com, or http://www.webbasedcron.com/